# VBA to add all files in a folder to an email

Tags: vba, excel

I have trying to send emails to a list of address and add the entire pdfs in a folder,

the code works the problem i have is that the files can be add only if i put a full path.

[image]

I want it to go to D and get all the pdfs or files from the folder and create email.

so again everything works except the attachments need a full path, but i just want to put the path of the folder and it will take all the files from it, 
thank you.

```
Sub massemailsend()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet



    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet


  For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A70")


    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)


        With objMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Body = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            '\\Attacment from here
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Display
        End With


        Set objMail = Nothing
    Next cell


    Set ws = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use this function, returning an array of all filenames matching your spec. You can super easily integrate that in your code.

```
Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant
'   Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'   If no matching files are found, it returns False

    Dim FileArray() As Variant
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim FileName As String

    On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

    FileCount = 0
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
    If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

    'Loop until no more matching files are found
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
        FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    GetFileList = FileArray
    Exit Function

    '   Error handler
NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function
```

Function comes from http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/getting_a_list_of_file_names_using_vba/

Answer (score 0):

If the path is always the same, define it at the top like this (include the trailing backslash)

```
Const myPath = "D:\FilesAreHere\"
```

Then change the attachment line to this:

```
.Attachments.Add myPath & cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
```

Comment: the path is not the same